# Problem to add a new block right after the current one

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, slatejs, react-slate

I'm trying to add a new block right after the block where the cursor is located / where I click on a button.

My questions are:

- How can I determine the path for the current block?
- Which method can I use to add a block after? I use `insertNode` but you can't specify a path when calling it... So the block is added at the very end of the list of blocks.

I saw that there is an optional parameter to the `insertNode` method but it's not documented  and doesn't seem to work:

```
const addedNode = editor.insertNode({
  type: 'p',
  children: [{ text: 'test' }]
}, {
  at: [ index + 1 ]
});
```

Thanks,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,
I believe SlateJS adds the new node after the current node by default.
Current node = where your cursor is.
If there is no selection (you havent placed your cursor anywhere) then it will place this block
[Node Transforms insertNodes](https://docs.slatejs.org/api/transforms#transforms-insertnodes-editor-editor-nodes-node-or-node-options)